# Posting a job offer for a company in the Philippines

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I would like my company to participate in Stack Overflow Careers. However, as I tried to post a new job offer, it seems that the Philippines is not yet supported, but I'm not sure.

One of the reason why I feel that is because there is no Philippine pesos in the available currencies.

[image]

Comment: Where does currency come up?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I notice that it's optional, sorry. So, for the meantime I can leave it as blank?

Comment: I suppose you can, but I agree the currency missing at that point isn't ideal.

Comment: If you can leave the currency out, maybe the best is to not select a currency there but mention in the main text that the salary range is in Philippine pesos. Interested people will understand.

Comment: @Trilarion .... and those who are giddy because they think they're going to be millionaires you can weed out right away! :)

Comment: No freehand circles?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Or you can just hire them and let them work until they figure out that their pay is 1/48 of what they thought it was going to be. :)

Comment: @reirab nah, man. We don't want to contribute to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rampage_killers_(workplace_killings)

Comment: At least you can offer wages in the [Pacific peso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_dollar)!